# show one element of a class and hide all others

Tags: jquery, class, animation, navigation, show-hide

Using the following function to hide all elements of a class before showing the right one. But I'm getting a double animation on the later elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/cR9bJ/16/

Function is called by an h2.

Function is:

```
function showSubList(obj) {
var elem = obj;
$('.sublist').hide(function() {
    $(elem).parent().children('.sublist').show();
});
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the elements first then show the one you want.

```
function showSubList(obj) {
    $('.sublist').hide(300);
    $(obj).parent().children('.sublist').show();
};​
```

This fixes the double animation.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/cR9bJ/22/)

Comment: it's always simpler than I try to make it :) thanks @François

Comment: as a good rule - you should avoid inline JS in your HTML when jQuery let you do that http://jsfiddle.net/cR9bJ/23/

Comment: @ZoltanToth: +1 I only fixed the existing code but if you were to change it the sliding looks real nice.